# Firefox strange single quotes conversion in urls

Tags: javascript, firefox, url-encoding

Does anybody know why FF encodes single quote `'` into `%27` ?

Single quote is supposed to be a valid char in URLs.
In-fact all other browser IE7/IE8/Chrome5/Safari4 work well by NOT encoding single quote into %27.

Is this a FF bug, or it's me that I'm missing something?

I'm testing with FF3.6.1

To easy test, simply add this in `yourpage.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.alert("this url = " + window.location.href);
</script>
```

Then go to `yourpage.html?test=quote'encoded`

FF won't replace the url in the address bar, but it will display:

```
yourpage.html?test=quote%27encoded
```

All other browsers will display

```
yourpage.html?test=quote'encoded
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox 4 (on Ubuntu) escapes the single quote as well.

Both Chromium 11.0.696.57 and Google Chrome 12.0.742.16 do not!

However, it should be noted that all characters **may** be encoded. It is legal to url-encode `A`, if one desires and it **should** be exactly equivalent to using `A` directly in your URL, so your code should be able to handle both versions.

From [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> On the other hand, characters that are not required to be encoded
>      (including alphanumerics) may be encoded within the scheme-specific
>      part of a URL, as long as they are not being used for a reserved
>      purpose.

Comment: +1 expecially when you say `it should be noted that all characters may be encoded...so your code should be able to handle both versions`.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: so url component can also be all url encoded, but `&` must never be translated into `&amp`, thus this url should be valid `url?key1=%27quote'&key2=val` whilest this one should be INVALID: `url?key1=%27quote'&amp;key2=val` Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure about it being invalid (because `;` is reserved according to RFC 1738 but has no special meaning in RFC 2616), but it's definitely not what was intended, as it *would* mean that the key `amp;key2` was assigned the value `val`.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I think `&amp;` is not valid because in PHP if you call `$_GET['key2']` on the url `url?key1=%27quote'&amp;key2=val` you get `NULL`

Comment: @Marco: and what do you get on `$_GET['amp;key2']`?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I get the correct value `val` of `key2`, but this proves that `&` must never be converted into `&amp;` when entering urls cause the server would not be able to properly read the `$_GET` parameters. Instead you prefectly right when you say `that all characters (of the GET query values) may be encoded`. Mine was just curiosity to complete the answer.